# Adding Outer Border to Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need to add an outer border to a JPG image (image has a solid background).

Using `context.stroke()` only adds an inner border and covers up the inner edges of the image, however I need to add an outer border to the image.

Example Image
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `canvas {border: 1px solid red}`? Or adding border to wrapper?

Comment: I need the border added to the canvas so that I can later download the image with the border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add to an image, convert it to a canvas that is bigger than the original image by n pixels and draw the border.

The function creates a new image with a border `amount` is the border width in pixels, `style` is the colour/style you want the border. and `image` is the original image. Returns the new image with border

```
function borderImage(image,amount,style){
     var paddedImage = document.createElement("canvas");  // create a new image 
     amount = Math.round(amount);  // ensure that the amount is a int value
     paddedImage.width = image.width + amount * 2; // set the size
     paddedImage.height = image.height + amount * 2;
     // get a context so you can draw on it
     var ctx = paddedImage.getContext("2d");
     ctx.strokeStyle = style;  // set the colour;
     ctx.lineWidth = amount;
     // draw the border
     ctx.strokeRect(amount / 2 , amount / 2, image.width + amount, image.height + amount);
     // draw the image on top
     ctx.drawImage(image, amount, amount);
     return paddedImage ; // return the new image
}
```

To use

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2n6E.png";
image.onload = function(){
    image = borderImage(this,8,"black");
    document.body.appendChild(image);
}
```

```js
    function borderImage(image,amount,style){
         var paddedImage = document.createElement("canvas");  // create a new image 
         amount = Math.round(amount);  // ensure that the amount is a int value
         paddedImage.width = image.width + amount * 2; // set the size
         paddedImage.height = image.height + amount * 2;
         // get a context so you can draw on it
         var ctx = paddedImage.getContext("2d");
         ctx.strokeStyle = style;  // set the colour;
         ctx.lineWidth = amount;
         // draw the border
         ctx.strokeRect(amount / 2 , amount / 2, image.width + amount, image.height + amount);
         // draw the image on top
         ctx.drawImage(image, amount, amount);
         return paddedImage ; // return the new image
    }


    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2n6E.png";
    image.onload = function(){
        image = borderImage(this,8,"black");
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
//assuming cvs is your canvas reference
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
cvs.width = yourImage.width;
cvs.height= yourImage.height;
ctx.lineWidth = x; // This is your border thickness
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.rect(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.drawImage(yourImage,x,x,cvs.width-2*x,cvs.height-2*x);
```

Your image size has been reduced a bit though to accomodate the borders. However there will be some lose in height and width (2 times the border width ).

If you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the original image after adding the border, you can change the last line to

```
ctx.drawImage(yourImage,x,x,cvs.width*(1- (2*x/cvs.width)),cvs.height*(1- (2*x/cvs.height)));
```